# PHP Exec Function Doesn't work with cd Ubuntu Command

Tags: php, ubuntu

Do you know why my exec() to change directory doesn't work when the script executes?

```
$test = exec('cd /var/www/mysite.com/mysite.com', $output);
echo $test;

$ls = exec('ls');
echo $ls;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the directory you are in use [`chdir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) instead

Answer (score 0):

`exec()` is for single commands. `cd` would change the directory, but then discard it for any future calls to `exec()`.

This would work though, since a path argument can be provided to `ls`:

```
echo exec('ls /var/www/mysite.com/mysite.com');
```

Comment: I don't really care about the ls.  I just want to be able to change the directory and make sure I'm in the right directory so I used ls.

Comment: @JasonBiondo What is the second command you're trying to run? Please edit your question. Posting irrelevant code helps nobody, and makes writing valid answers a waste of time.